# const std::shared_ptr<const T> as argument of a function ends up changing the values of the class in the smart pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, smart-pointers

I am having some problems with a small code that I am developing. It is essentially a geometric library where I define a class for 3D points and an abstract class for a 3D surface and then I implement different surfaces (planes, cones...). The library is built in templates (and it has to be so I can use it in [ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org)). The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is this:

**point.h**

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, int n>
class Surface;

template <typename T>
class Point
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Point<T>> Ptr;
  typedef std::shared_ptr<const Point<T>> ConstPtr;
  Point(T&& x, T&& y, T&& z)
  {
    data_[0] = x;
    data_[1] = y;
    data_[2] = z;
    std::cout << "Point constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  Point(const T* data)
  {
    std::cout << "Cosntructor point from data ptr" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      data_[i] = data[i];
  }
  Point(const Point<T>& other) : Point(other.data_)
  {
    std::cout << "Constructor copy point" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Point()
  {
    std::cout << "Point destructor" << std::endl;
  }

  template <int n>
  T distance(const std::shared_ptr<const Surface<T, n>> surface) const
  {
    std::cout << "\n1: " << *this << std::endl;
    ConstPtr a(this);
    std::cout << "2: " << *this << std::endl;
    T d = surface->distance(a);
    std::cout << "3: " << *this << std::endl;
    return d;
  }

  T& operator[](size_t i)
  {
    return data_[i];
  }

  T operator[](size_t i) const
  {
    return data_[i];
  }

  T& x()
  {
    std::cout << "x&" << std::endl;
    return data_[0];
  }

  T& y()
  {
    return data_[1];
  }

  T& z()
  {
    return data_[2];
  }

  T x() const
  {
    return data_[0];
  }

  T y() const
  {
    return data_[1];
  }

  T z() const
  {
    return data_[2];
  }

private:
  T data_[3];
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<T>& point)
{
  os << "[";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    if (i != 0)
    {
      os << ",";
    }
    os << point[i];
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}

#endif  // POINT_H
```

**surface.h**

```
#ifndef SURFACE_H
#define SURFACE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Point;

template <typename T, int n>
class Surface
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Surface<T, n>> Ptr;
  typedef std::shared_ptr<const Surface<T, n>> ConstPtr;
  Surface()
  {
    std::cout << "Surface constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Surface()
  {
    std::cout << "Surface destructor" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual T distance(const std::shared_ptr<const Point<T>> point) const = 0;

  T& operator[](size_t i)
  {
    return data_[i];
  }

  T operator[](size_t i) const
  {
    return data_[i];
  }

protected:
  T data_[n];
};

#endif  // SURFACE_H
```

**plane.h**

```
#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H
#include "surface.h"

#include <math.h>

template <typename T>
class Point;

template <typename T>
class Plane : public virtual Surface<T, 4>
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Plane<T>> Ptr;
  typedef std::shared_ptr<const Plane<T>> ConstPtr;
  using Surface<T, 4>::data_;
  Plane(T&& nx, T&& ny, T&& nz, T&& d)
  {
    data_[0] = nx;
    data_[1] = ny;
    data_[2] = nz;
    data_[3] = d;
    std::cout << "Plane constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  Plane(const T* data)
  {
    std::cout << "Cosntructor plane from data ptr" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      data_[i] = data[i];
  }
  Plane(const Plane<T>& other) : Plane(other.data_)
  {
    std::cout << "Constructor copy plane" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Plane()
  {
    std::cout << "Plane destructor" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual T distance(const std::shared_ptr<const Point<T>> point) const override
  {
    return (data_[0] * point->x() + data_[1] * point->y() + data_[2] * point->z() - data_[3]) /
           sqrt(pow(data_[0], 2) + pow(data_[1], 2) + pow(data_[2], 2));
  }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Plane<T>& plane)
{
  os << plane[0] << "*x+" << plane[1] << "*y+" << plane[2] << "*z = " << plane[3];
  return os;
}

#endif  // PLANE_H
```

**Main**

```
#include "plane.h"
#include "point.h"
int main()
{
  Point<float>::Ptr point(new Point<float>(100, 100, 1.6));
  Plane<float>::Ptr plane(new Plane<float>(1, 2, 3, -10));
  float d1 = plane->distance(point);
  std::cout << "Distance from " << *point << " to " << *plane << " -> " << d1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Point " << *point << "; Plane " << *plane << std::endl;
  float d2 = point->distance<4>(plane);
  std::cout << "Distance from " << *point << " to " << *plane << " -> " << d2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Point " << *point << "; Plane " << *plane << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This produces the right distance outputs. However, if I use `Point::distance` method the `x` and `y` values of the point are changed to `0` while if I use `Plane::distance`, the `x` and `y` of the point are not changed. In both cases the `distance` method are const and have as input `const std::shared_ptr<const Plane<T>>` and `const std::shared_ptr<const Point<T>>`.

**My question:**
How is it possible that the values of the Point are changed if everything is set to `const`?

I have the filling that this happens when the `ConstPtr a(this)` in `Point::distance` is destructed, but I do not even know which constructor is being used to create the `ConstPtr a(this)` in the `Ponit::distance` method.

The output of the program is:

```
Point constructor
Surface constructor
Plane constructor
Distance from [100,100,1.6] to 1*x+2*y+3*z = -10 -> 84.1338
Point [100,100,1.6]; Plane 1*x+2*y+3*z = -10
1: [100,100,1.6]
2: [100,100,1.6]
3: [100,100,1.6]
Point destructor
Distance from [0,0,1.6] to 1*x+2*y+3*z = -10 -> 84.1338
Point [0,0,1.6]; Plane 1*x+2*y+3*z = -10
Plane destructor
Surface destructor
Point destructor
```

Comment: It's possible if there's undefined behavior anywhere in the code, at which points all bets are off. When faced with a change to some variable, that I do not expect, I simply have my debugger set up a hardware watch on the variable, and seconds later the debugger tells me where my bug is. Have you tried using your debugger to analyze this code, yet, and if not why not?

Comment: `ConstPtr a(this);` does not create a new instance and it is not aware that the object is already being managed by another `shared_ptr`. You should check out [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: Can you explain to me or point me to a tutorial where I can see this? I've used the debugger in QtCreator but only so I know where my `segmentation faults` are.

Comment: @UnholySheep that solved it! If you post it as and answer you'll get accepted!

Comment: You also have issue with `Point(const T* data)
  {
    std::cout << "Cosntructor point from data ptr" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      data_[i] = data[i];
  }` as `data_[3]` is out of bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues lies in `ConstPtr a(this);` - this line creates a `std::shared_ptr` that takes ownership of the current object and `delete`s it after it goes out of scope.
Due to this the `point` pointer becomes a *dangling pointer* after the call `float d2 = point->distance<4>(plane);` and dereferencing it leads to *undefined behavior*

In order to fix the issue the `Point` class needs to inherit from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and the line `ConstPtr a(this);` needs to become `ConstPtr a(shared_from_this());`